Primevue dynamic datatable in flexible dialog
I have an application showing lots of data in tables, most of which have dynamic column configurations retrieved from the server. Since there a potentially a lot of rows, I'd also like to use the datatable's virtual scroller feature.
Tables shown in pages filling the window work fine, but I'm having troubles with showing them in a flexible sized dialog:

few rows, no need to have a full-height dialog
few columns, no need to have a full-width dialog
lots of rows, full height dialog with vertical scrolling in the table
lots of columns, full width dialog with horizontal scrolling in the table

Does anyone have a template/configuration which works in all cases?
